# Free webcam software for laptop (Dell 15R N5110)

Tags: windows-7, laptop, webcam

I installed the [Dell Webcam Center](http://dell-webcam-center.software.informer.com/) software from Dell but it seems it does not support my Dell 15R N5110 webcam or the Windows 7 64-bit web cam driver. I get the following error:

> No supported webcam driver detected

Can anyone suggest some good free webcam software that allows me to take pictures with the integrated webcam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found working [Dell Webcam Center](http://downloads.dell.com/monitors/Dell_SX2210-Monitor_Webcam%20SW%20RC1.1_%20R230103.exe) for Dell N5110, here:

http://drivers.downloadatoz.com/tutorial/27444,how-to-fix-dell-inspiron-n5110-integrated-webcam-not-working-problem.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your webcam *driver* (the software that interacts between the hardware and operating system) instead of the webcam *software* (which just communicates with the operating system).

Go to the Device manager (Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, enter `devmgmt.msc`, and press Enter). Make sure that your webcam is enabled. If there is a driver problem with it , right-click and select `Update driver software` and follow the instructions.

Comment: I think Integrated Web Cam driver is installed correctly, driver manufacturer is Microsoft (not Dell). There is no web cam driver for the particular model to download in dell site.

Comment: @Nalaka526 Yup, the webcam should work fine with the generic drivers from Microsoft. Can you access the webcam with any other software, such as vlc or skype?

Comment: Found compatible software (Dell Webcam Central) with my laptop http://drivers.downloadatoz.com/tutorial/27444,how-to-fix-dell-inspiron-n5110-integrated-webcam-not-working-problem.html